# Text input via button

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, list, button

I have 4 buttons on my form and I want the user to input his word by clicking up, down, left and right on the buttons.

[Image of the example form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eaJA.png)

The user can choose his letter, number or symbol by going up and down.

Left and right will be for going back and forth in the word. Back in case he made a mistake and forward in case he wants to confirm his current letter.

these are the variables

```
private string word;

private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

private char[] wordsAndLetters = { ' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', ',', '.', '!', '?' };
```

Now we need to give the buttons the option to go between the letters, etc.

```
    private int i;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tbOutput.Text = word;         
    }

    private void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //We don't want the i to go above the array
        if (i <= 39)
        {
            i = i + 1;
        }
        tbOutput.Text = word + Convert.ToString(wordsAndLetters[i]);      
    }

    private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //We don't want the i to go below the array
        if (i > 0)
        {
            i = i - 1;
        }
        tbOutput.Text = word + Convert.ToString(wordsAndLetters[i]);
    }

    private void btnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbOutput.Text = word;
        sb.Append(wordsAndLetters[i]);
        word = sb.ToString();
        i = 0;
        tbOutput.Clear();
        tbOutput.Text = word;
    }

    private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int lengthword = sb.Length;
        sb.Remove(lengthword -1, 1);
        word = sb.ToString();
        tbOutput.Clear();
        tbOutput.Text = word;
    }
}
```

This is what I have right now and it works but it isn't flawless. Do you guys have any way of making my current program better?

Comment: Take a look at `StringBuilder` and `.Append(char)`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot technically add to an existing string, as they are immutable. Instead, here are a couple simple options:

1) Concatenate the new character each time.

```
word += wordsAndLetters[i];
//Which is the same as:
//word = word + wordsAndLetters[i];
```

2) Use a `StringBuilder` as Jay mentions in his comment to your post.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(wordsAndLetters[i]);
word = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I have updated my code and it works right now :)

Comment: Great @imsohateful!